# how deploy sharepoint workspace 2010

Tags: sharepoint-online

my system is of 32 bit with windows XP pro operating system. I have installed 32bit office professional plus 2010 package. I want to set sharepoint workspace in my system with ability to access my sharepoint workspace. I would like to know from where should I begin with? And will i be able to install sharepoint server 2010 on my system?